# How can i install a python library which have not a install.py?

Tags: python, installation, package

This is the first time im installing a python library which does not have `install.py`. What's the best approach to install it and import it in my project?

The lib in question is: https://github.com/hoonto/pygeometry

Comment: "pip install pygeometry", installs andreacensi's pygeometry, a differen't project.

Comment: oh?! I thought they were the same. Sorry - deleting my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Follow the readme file in the repository, it contains all the necessary instructions to build and install.